# feature detection firefox quirk with title attributes not showing on disabled elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, browser-feature-detection

How would I go about using feature detection to find out whether I need to emulate the title attribute on disabled input elements.

I'm aware that firefox claims & interprets the specification so that it is working as intended but I would none the less like tooltips to display.

The only thing I can think of is using browser detection directly.

an example of the issue can be seen here http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/xQyBR/

```
var con = $("#Con");

var b1 = $("<input>").attr({
    "id": "b1",
    "title": "Some Other Text",
    "type": "button",
    "value": "b1"  
}).appendTo(con);

con.append($("<br>"));

var b2 = $("<input>").attr({
    "id": "b2",
    "title": "Some text",
    "type": "button",
    "value": "b2",
    "disabled": true
}).appendTo(con);


var detected = $("input:disabled[title]");
console.log(detected);
```

Using jQuery is acceptable.

Comment: I think that it might be a little strange for users to see tooltips on disabled inputs; I offer the suggestion that you make the tooltip somehow indicate that the field is disabled (as well as providing whatever information you need).

Comment: The intention of the tooltip is to say _why_ the input is disabled. For example "this button is disabled because you have not selected anything in the datalist" or "you do not have the neccesary permissions, please contact so & so if neccesary"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is no feature detection for this (afaik). But you might want to workaround this issue with a transparent div overlay.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xQyBR/19/

Example with plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/xQyBR/24/

That way, it'll be cross-browser compatible anyway.

Comment: Then we reach problems with enabling it and trying to click it. Remembering to destroy, move or hide the div every time the button is enabled isnt really a good solution.

Comment: @Raynos: Using this technique should imply to use somekind of a self-written plugin `.enable()` & `.disabled()` which does the job for you.

Comment: Oh god you implemented it as $.fn.enable & $.fn.disable. That's never going to namespace clash.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution to emulating title's would be to use CSS only. A combination of `:after` and `:hover` allows you to create tooltips on the fly and doesn't break the use of `input.disabled`

http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/cgYgR/